# How to preload the child collections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A `User` has many friends, and each friend has an `Address`.

I am currently doing this:

```
User.includes(:friends).find(1)
```

In my view I am then looping through all of the friends and displaying their address.

Is there a way I can preload the addresses also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) You can load nested relationships as well by using a Hash like following:

```
users = User.includes(friends: [:address])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get address by doing this :-

```
User.includes(friends: :address)
```